# Selecting all rows from last month onward

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all the data from the previous month to all the months in the future .. for example , I'd like to select everything from January till any date available in the future on the database, that goes for any month .. select the previous month till the future months of this year

This is my QUERY, It only starts with February , how can I make it start with the previous month .. current month - 1 is not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE YEAR(event_start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
  AND MONTH(event_start_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Comment: You mean between a start date and end date ?

Comment: For best performance, we'd prefer a predicate on the bare `event_start_date` column; that would allow for an index range scan (if an appropriate index is available), rather than having MySQL evaluate every row in the table. The "trick" is coming up with an expression that uses the current datetime and returns the first day of the previous month, e.g. `event_start_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW()+INTERVAL -1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')`

Answer (score 0):

use `DATE_SUB()` to select previous month and `>=` to select all data in the future:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE YEAR(event_start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
  AND MONTH(event_start_date) >= MONTH(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
AND MONTH(event_start_date) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTHS))
```

The portion `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` will subtract a month from the current date. If you want last month and everything in the future, use:

```
AND MONTH(event_start_date) >= MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTHS))
```

Notice '>='. Although there is an edge case at january that you'll have to get around. The best way might be like this:

```
WHERE event_start_date >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTHS), (DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE)) DAYS)
```

Which will get you everything from the 1st of last month. No edge cases.

Comment: since he's only selecting a specific year, edge case wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: if he wants to get the last month, from last year, it is indeed an important edge case.

Comment: well in that case, `YEAR(event_start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ` would not allow him to select anything from last year.

Comment: `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTHS (DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE)-1) DAYS)` has syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, I guess you can't use two intervals

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE YEAR(event_start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND MONTH(event_start_date) >= MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE event_start_date >= '1/'+MONTH(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))+'/'+YEAR(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, you'd likely want an index range scan operation on the `event_start_date` column. That means (obviously), you'd want an index with `event_start_date` as a leading column.

To get an index range scan, the predicate needs to be on the bare `event_start_date` column, and NOT a function.

```
WHERE event_start_date >= some_value
```

For "some_value" in this case, one possible expression you can use would be:

```
CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW()+INTERVAL -1 MONTH ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE)
```

That takes the current date and time, subtracts one month, and then sets the day and time component to midnight of the first of the month.